# Why doesn't Toht talk much?

Tags: character-motivation, indiana-jones, raiders-of-the-lost-ark

In *Raiders of the Lost Ark* he seems to be quiet during the majority of the film.

This is the character I am referring to:

[image: Roth as seen in the movie]

Comment: Because he doesn't need to. His presence and appearance are enough

Comment: I remember him having at least one line in every scene he appeared in... IMO he didn't have enough screen time in general to have massive amounts of dialogue.

Comment: He has 16 lines in total...and held your attention with every word and move.

Comment: Toht's role was dramatically scaled back during the scripting phase. Apparently he was going to have interchangeable arms (gun, flamethrower) and a robotic red glowing eye. Lucas put his foot down.  http://forum.rebelscum.com/showthread.php?t=1074079

Comment: "*Spielberg: Our biggest dispute was that I had this heavy-metal view of the character of Toht (Ronald Lacey). I saw him with a prosthetic hand that was in fact a machine gun and a flamethrower. He was like The Terminator before The Terminator. We've got the artwork to prove it. That's where George put his foot down and said, "Steven, you're crossing out of one genre and into another." I agreed. All that hard work just became refuse in the art department.*": http://www.empireonline.com/movies/features/indiana-jones-making-raiders-lost-ark/

Comment: @Skooba He appears but doesn't speak at all starting with the march across the island to the altar to open the ark at the end. He mops his head with a handkerchief around the time Indy ducks out of line to grab the RPG. The only sound he makes in the whole ending sequence is laughter when Belloq discovers only sand in the Ark. At the same time, pretty much the same can be said for Marion Ravenwood (she yells "Indyyyy.." when the maelstrom surrounds them). Paulie D's count is probably correct, and is a decent amount for a character.

Answer (score 4):

## Behind the scenes, some of his material was cut

In [an interview](https://www.empireonline.com/movies/features/indiana-jones-making-raiders-lost-ark/) in issue 227 of *Empire* magazine, Steven Spielberg revealed that the character was "like The Terminator before The Terminator", but George Lucas vetoed it.

> **Spielberg:** Our biggest dispute was that I had this heavy-metal view of the character of Toht [Ronald Lacey]. I saw him with a prosthetic hand that was in fact a machine gun and a flamethrower. He was like The Terminator before The Terminator. We've got the artwork to prove it. That's where George put his foot down and said, "Steven, you're crossing out of one genre and into another." I agreed. All that hard work just became refuse in the art department.

It's possible that Toht had additional dialogue related to this, but it was cut along with the design.

## Thematically, speaking less gives his words have extra weight

TV Tropes calls this sort of character [The Quiet One](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TheQuietOne)

> This character isn't The Speechless, and is "definitely" not The Voiceless. Nor are they the Ineffectual Loner. They just rarely talk, so anything which IS said carries extra weight.

By speaking so rarely, viewers pay additional attention to the few words that Toht does say. This also makes him a bit more mysterious and unnerving; he speaks differently than Indy, Marion, and the other characters, separating him from them.